# i need a little help with a text box

Tags: c#-4.0

```
 if (textBox1.Text == "Alabama" || textBox1.Text == "alabama")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0570;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Alaska" || textBox1.Text == "alaska")
        {
            StateTax = 0.1167;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Arizona" || textBox1.Text == "arizona")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0592;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Arkansas" || textBox1.Text == "arkansas")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0835;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "California" || textBox1.Text == "california")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0739;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Colorado" || textBox1.Text == "colorado")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0272;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Connecticut" || textBox1.Text == "connecticut")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0654;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Deleware" || textBox1.Text == "deleware")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0825;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Florida" || textBox1.Text == "flordia")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0503;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Georgia" || textBox1.Text == "georgia")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0562;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Hawaii" || textBox1.Text == "hawaii")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0985;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Idaho" || textBox1.Text == "idaho")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0736;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Illinois" || textBox1.Text == "illinois")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0562;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Indiana" || textBox1.Text == "indiana")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0648;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Iowa" || textBox1.Text == "iowa")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0591;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Kansas" || textBox1.Text == "kansas")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0654;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Kentucky" || textBox1.Text == "kentucky")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0734;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Louisiana" || textBox1.Text == "louisiana")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0685;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Maine" || textBox1.Text == "maine")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0770;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Maryland" || textBox1.Text == "maryland")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0559;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Massachusetts" || textBox1.Text == "massachusetts")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0630;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Michigan" || textBox1.Text == "Michigan")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0672;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Minnesota" || textBox1.Text == "minnesota")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0802;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Mississippi" || textBox1.Text == "mississippi")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0740;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Missouri" || textBox1.Text == "missouri")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0517;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Montana" || textBox1.Text == "montana")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0708;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Nebraska" || textBox1.Text == "nebraska")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0610;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Nevada" || textBox1.Text == "nevada")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0612;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "New Hampshire" || textBox1.Text == "new hampshire")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0387;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "New Jersey" || textBox1.Text == "new jersey")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0661;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "New Mexico" || textBox1.Text == "new mexico")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0826;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "New York" || textBox1.Text == "new york")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0676;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "North Carolina" || textBox1.Text == "north carolina")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0726;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "North Dakota" || textBox1.Text == "north dakota")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0711;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Ohio" || textBox1.Text == "Ohio")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0609;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Oklahoma" || textBox1.Text == "oklahoma")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0621;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Oregon" || textBox1.Text == "oregon")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0576;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Pennsylvania" || textBox1.Text == "pennsylvania")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0617;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Rhode Island" || textBox1.Text == "rhode island")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0640;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "South Carolina" || textBox1.Text == "south carolina")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0619;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "South Dakota" || textBox1.Text == "south dakota")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0423;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Tennessee" || textBox1.Text == "tennessee")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0539;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Texas" || textBox1.Text == "texas")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0438;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Utah" || textBox1.Text == "utah")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0728;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Vermont" || textBox1.Text == "vermont")
        {
            StateTax = 0.1060;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Virginia" || textBox1.Text == "virginia")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0563;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Washington" || textBox1.Text == "washington")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0648;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "West Virginia" || textBox1.Text == "west virginia")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0834;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Wisconsin" || textBox1.Text == "wisconsin")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0693;
        }if (textBox1.Text == "Wyoming" || textBox1.Text == "wyoming")
        {
            StateTax = 0.0778;
        } if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            string messageBoxText = "Their is No State Entered into the first pages State Textbox";
            MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText);
            return;

        }
```

So i really just need the assigned values to be able to be assigned by the name entered, which i have working now i just need it so that only those words can be entered, nothing more.
If you could help me that would be great, i posted once before but i realized that i had the whole thing crammed together.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "so that only those words can be entered" -- because a user can enter anything they want in a text box and there's not much you can do to stop them. You may want to rephrase what you really mean in that case.

Comment: My first step would be to simplify the code. Not to be harsh, but this is the sort of code found on tdwtf. I would recommend using a Dictionary and string-case normalization as a start. Now, as far as the "question", consider a restrictive control type such as a ListBox or ComboBox.

Comment: Why not have a listbox/combobox to allow the user to choose the states? And if the listbox/combobox is bound to a State class that includes the name and tax, the tax can be determined based on the selected item.

Comment: Why is this a textbox and not a dropdown list populated from a simple SQL table?

Comment: @Joe Phillips  Well your the only one who didn't understand what it meant, its quit simple. i didn't want anyone to be able to enter text that didn't have an assigned value of my own, so in other words not a state or one of the 50 states then throw an exception.

Comment: @pst   so i did simplfy the code to a dictionary, and have an if statement i just cant get the values to pass to my double. To Everyone else asking about taking the rout of a listbox, i have done this but it is my users of my application who would like more design in the background and i figured a textbox is the best way to hold that data, before i had a check list with the states and a listbox, i also threw a stackpanel down and a listbox with check boxes in it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a Listbox then you decide what state names the user can select and you dont have to check if a state name is valid.  Add a ListBox control to your form and populate it.

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Alabama");
listBox1.Items.Add("Arizona");
listBox1.Items.Add("Arkansas");
```

Then do something like:

```
 Double StateTax = 0;

if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
{
     switch (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower())
            {
                case "alabama": StateTax = 0.0570; break;
                case "arizona": StateTax = 0.0570; break;
                case "arkansas": StateTax = 0.0570; break;
                /* etc... */

                default: break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

**Binding**

```
string allStateTaxes = "Alabama+0.0570|Alaska+0.1167| ... |Wisconsin+0.0778";

Dictionary<string,string> stateTaxes = new Dictionary<string,string>();
string[] stateTaxSplit = null;

foreach(string stateTax in stateTaxes.Split('|'))
{
     stateTaxSplit = stateTax.Split('+');
     stateTaxes.Add(stateTaxSplit[0], stateTaxSplit[1]);  
}

listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(stateTaxes, null); 
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"; 
listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

**Searching**

```
string strTax = null;
float tax;

if(stateTaxes.TryGetValue(state, out strTax)) {
   // state is found; strTax is set
   tax = float.Parse(strTax);
} else {
   // state not found; strTax is null
}
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of the string stuff -- string typing is nice -- but +1 for showing how to data-bind.

Comment: @pst: actually I was aiming for the string to be the major advantage over any other local process storage method to shorten the code: if you look at the format chosen its a)readable b)short c) maintainable d)constant (meaning can be used as a constant-change-one-place type of thing) . I think this is likely the best way to go about if you are presented to bind a ddl or listbox with this specific data (all states & taxes for it) EDIT: also this is good performance, not that it matters but for the record

Comment: Doh I meant "strict" typing. My reason for opting against a string is that it allows typed expansion later, if required. I would likely use a `Dictionary<string,float>`, which could later be expanded to `Dictionary<string,StateInformation>` or similar -- I entirely agree about keeping it entirely in one place!

Answer (score 0):

You might try an InputBox:

```
Dim state as String
state = InputBox("What is your name?","User Input")
textBox1.Test = state
```